# Reorder JS Object with specific order

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON Object (Array of Arrays) that I need to filter with a specific order:

```
order: ['Hors','TTC','Total général', 'verger', ' Tra']

data = [[" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"]
[" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"]
[" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"]
[" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"]
[" Tra", "Total", ""]
["Comparable", "", ""]
["Hors", "", ""]
["TTC", "", ""]
["Total général", "", ""]
["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"]
["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"]
["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"]
["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"]]
```

I tried to use sort() but I doesn't fit my needs and some string contains spaces:

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return data.sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b)) ;

});
```

This solution doesn't get me what I need, but stille the same Object

Comment: JSON is a string representation of JavaScript Objects. Unless you are having issues with converting to/from a JSON *string*, the JSON tag is not relevant.

Comment: after what you want so sort? which column. and then start or end? the duration? please be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wan all your data returned but sorted like in the order array you could use filter like this

```js
order= ['Hors','TTC','Total général', 'vergers', ' Tra']
const data = [ [" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"], [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"], [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"], [" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"], [" Tra", "Total", ""], ["Comparable", "", ""], ["Hors", "", ""], ["TTC", "", ""], ["Total général", "", ""], ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"], ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"], ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"], ["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"] ]

function sort(order){
   result=[]
   order.forEach(el =>result.push(data.filter(o=>el==o[0])));
   result.unshift(data.filter(o=>!order.some(y=>y==o[0])))
  return result.flat()
}
console.log(sort(order))
```

if you want to filter and sort only the element from order array you can try this

```js
order= ['Hors','TTC','Total général', 'vergers', ' Tra']
const data = [ [" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"], [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"], [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"], [" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"], [" Tra", "Total", ""], ["Comparable", "", ""], ["Hors", "", ""], ["TTC", "", ""], ["Total général", "", ""], ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"], ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"], ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"], ["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"] ]

function sort(order){
   result=[]
   order.forEach(el =>result.push(data.filter(o=>el==o[0])));
  return result.flat()
}
console.log(sort(order))
```

Comment: Great thank you. How can I order my data to sort and put my 'orders' elements at then end? And not at the beginning

Comment: I have updated the code (first snippet) so that your ordered elements will show last and your unordered element will show first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by the first element of each array this should work:

(I changed 'verger' to 'vergers'. I guess that was a typo)

```js
var order = ['Hors','TTC','Total général', 'vergers', ' Tra']

var data = [
  [" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"],
  [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"],
  [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"],
  [" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"],
  [" Tra", "Total", ""],
  ["Comparable", "", ""],
  ["Hors", "", ""],
  ["TTC", "", ""],
  ["Total général", "", ""],
  ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"],
  ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"],
  ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"],
  ["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"]
];

data.sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a[0]) - order.indexOf(b[0])) ;

console.log(data)
```

If you also want to filter out non-matching elements:

```js
var order = ['Hors','TTC','Total général', 'vergers', ' Tra']

var data = [
  [" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"],
  [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"],
  [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"],
  [" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"],
  [" Tra", "Total", ""],
  ["Comparable", "", ""],
  ["Hors", "", ""],
  ["TTC", "", ""],
  ["Total général", "", ""],
  ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"],
  ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"],
  ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"],
  ["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"]
];

data = data
  .filter(x => order.indexOf(x[0]) > -1)
  .sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a[0]) - order.indexOf(b[0]));

console.log(data)
```

Comment: The first example doesn't work, I still have the same array. The second array gaves me this result :
data =   ["Total général", "", ""],

Comment: You can see for yourself that it works. Just press the "run code snippet" button :) The results look nothing like the array you described.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    [" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"],
    [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"],
    [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"],
    [" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"],
    [" Tra", "Total", ""],
    ["Comparable", "", ""],
    ["Hors", "", ""],
    ["TTC", "", ""],
    ["Total général", "", ""],
    ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"],
    ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"],
    ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"],
    ["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"]
  ]
  
  function sequence(arr) {
    return arr.filter(ele => ["Hors","TTC", "Total général"].some(val => val === ele[0]))
      .concat(arr.filter(ele => ele[0] === "vergers"))
      .concat(arr.filter(ele => ele[0] === " Tra"))
  }
  
  console.log(sequence(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `indexOf(a)` / `indexOf(b)` but `indexOf(a[0])` / `indexOf(b[0])` because you want to compare the first element of each array, not the whole array.

```
const order = ['Hors','TTC','Total général', 'vergers', ' Tra'];                
                                                                                
const data = [                                                                  
    [" Tra", "100 - 149 ch", "Total"],                                          
    [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "150 - 159 ch"],                                   
    [" Tra", "150 - 199 ch", "160 - 169 ch"],                                   
    [" Tra", "500 - 999 ch", "Total"],                                          
    [" Tra", "Total", ""],                                                      
    ["Comparable", "", ""],                                                     
    ["Hors", "", ""],                                                           
    ["TTC", "", ""],                                                            
    ["Total général", "", ""],                                                  
    ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "20 - 29 ch"],                                   
    ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "30 - 39 ch"],                                   
    ["vergers", "  1 - 49 ch", "40 - 49 ch"],                                   
    ["vergers", " 50 - 99 ch", "70 - 79 ch"],                                   
];                                                                              
                                                                                
    /* const weights = Object.fromEntries( */                                   
    /*     order.map((k,i)=>[k,i]) */                                           
    /* ); */                                                                    
    /* console.log(weights); */                                                 
                                                                                
function sortByOrder(data, order) {                                             
    const weight = Object.fromEntries(                                          
        // Pre-cache indexOf(...)                                               
        order.map((k,i)=>[k,i])                                                 
    );                                                                          
    return data.sort(                                                           
        ([a],[b])=>weight[a]-weight[b]                                          
    );                                                                          
};                                                                              
                                                                                
console.log(sortByOrder(data,order));                                           
                                                                                
// [ [ 'Hors', '', '' ],                                                        
//   [ 'TTC', '', '' ],                                                         
//   [ 'Total général', '', '' ],                                               
//   [ 'vergers', '  1 - 49 ch', '30 - 39 ch' ],                                
//   [ 'vergers', '  1 - 49 ch', '20 - 29 ch' ],                                
//   [ 'Comparable', '', '' ],                                                  
//   [ 'vergers', ' 50 - 99 ch', '70 - 79 ch' ],                                
//   [ 'vergers', '  1 - 49 ch', '40 - 49 ch' ],                                
//   [ ' Tra', '150 - 199 ch', '150 - 159 ch' ],                                
//   [ ' Tra', 'Total', '' ],                                                   
//   [ ' Tra', '500 - 999 ch', 'Total' ],                                       
//   [ ' Tra', '150 - 199 ch', '160 - 169 ch' ],                                
//   [ ' Tra', '100 - 149 ch', 'Total' ] ]
```